# MySQL Trigger programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I have problem with creating a simple MySQL trigger in C#.
I'm using StringBuilder to build the following command string:

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `dbname`.`table`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `dbname`.`inserttrigger` AFTER INSERT ON `dbname`.`table`

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

...

END;

$$

DELIMITER ;

when I try cmd.executeNonQuery() an Exception occurs (Error in SQL syntax) which is despite the new lines referring to LINE 1. - The Stringbuilder will put in "\r\n" for every AppendLine().

If I copy and paste the command to the MySQL console it runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to [have been a bug in MySQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46429) with the `DELIMITER` statement, not sure it's the same you're hitting. Was fixed in a recent version of MySQL. If you're not using the latest version, try to update MySQL and try again.

Comment: Thanks Abel.
I'm using 5.0.77. I'll upgrade to 5.1.